# Como meter um ";" no fim da string, programa em c

Tags: c++, string, memória

Gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para o ";" no print aparecer **depois** da string e não **antes**.
Sou novo em programação e gostava de apelar à vossa ajuda.

Obrigado

**Input**

```
Linha1
Linha2
Linha3
Linha4
```

**Output esperado**

```
Produtos:
- Linha3;
- Linha4;
- Linha2;
- Linha1;
```

**Output obtido**

```
Produtos:
- Linha1
;- Linha2
;- Linha3
;- Linha4
;
```

**Código**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   

typedef struct linha {
  char *produtos;
  struct linha *prev;
} linha;

FILE *file;   
int main() {

  linha *tail = NULL;
  file = fopen("text.txt","r");
  char linha1[255];

  while (fgets(linha1,255,file)!=NULL) {
    linha *l1 =(linha*) malloc(sizeof(linha));
    l1->produtos =(char*) malloc(strlen(linha1)+1);
    strcpy(l1->produtos,linha1);
    l1->prev = tail;
    tail = l1;
  }

  linha *current;
  current = tail;
    printf("Produtos:\n");
  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("- %s;",current->produtos);
    current = current->prev;
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Editada, pois se o arquivo sendo lido não terminasse com uma quebra de linha (`'\n'`), o último caractere seria eliminado. Colocado um teste para verificar se o último caractere da linha lida é `'\n'` antes de substituir.

Como o user72726 explicou na resposta dele, a função fgets inclui o avanço de linha ao ler do arquivo (`'\n'`). A princípio eu pensei em inserir o ponto-e-vírgula ao ler o arquivo, mas isto limita algum outro tratamento que você pode querer fazer.

Eu sugiro tirar este avanço de linha ao ler do arquivo

```
while (fgets(linha1,255,file)!=NULL) {
  linha *l1 =(linha*) malloc(sizeof(linha));
  if (linha1[strlen(linha1) - 1] == '\n') // testa se o último caractere é \n
    linha1[strlen(linha1) - 1] = '\0'; // troca o \n pelo char null
  l1->produtos =(char*) malloc(strlen(linha1)+1);
  strcpy(l1->produtos,linha1);
  l1->prev = tail;
  tail = l1;
}
```

e depois adicionar o ponto-e-vírgula e o avanço de linha ao exibir na tela

```
while (current != NULL) {
  printf("- %s;\n",current->produtos);
  current = current->prev;
}
```

Funciona porque as funções que tratam strings param ao encontrar um caractere nulo - veja na ref. da strcpy do link abaixo, no final da primeira frase "including the terminating null character (and stopping at that point)".

<strike>Note que se fizer `sizeof(linha1)` vai ficar diferente de `strlen(linha1)`,  o normal, se não me engano, é a diferença ser 1 mas aqui será 2 porque `linha1` é um ponteiro que no final tem dois caracteres nulos ao invés de 1, que a strlen não conta.</strike>

O Parágrafo acima está incorreto porque `sizeof(linha1)` no caso desse programa será sempre 255, pois é o tamanho alocado na declaração.

Uma coisa importante, embora fora do assunto da pergunta, é liberar toda a memória que você usa. Então, se fosse eu, para cada malloc eu colocaria um memfree no programa mesmo que o programa fosse fechar logo depois.

Referências (outras funções aparecem no menu à esquerda):
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: adicionar o caractere nulo vai causar vazamento de memória, porque assim você está descartando o `\0` original. Embora não seje muita coisa (1byte), é uma boa prática devolver toda memória ao OS.

Comment: @user72726 Acho que não, pois o compilador tem informação de quanta memória o ponteiro (linha1) usa, ele não depende dos métodos de tratamento de string para saber quanta memória ele precisa liberar, ele já sabe. Só estamos enganando as funções que mexem com a string, não o gerenciamento de memória.

Comment: @user72726 Eu nem tinha notado, o array linha1 é declarado com tamanho 255, mais simples ainda, não há problema em trocar caractere de fim de linha pelo null. Sempre serão liberados 255 bytes de , o conteúdo não importa. Na realidade esse programa não tem nenhum memfree, com certeza eu colocaria um para cada malloc. Vou incluir um comentário disso na resposta agora mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

O função `fgets` retorna todos os caractere da linha, incluindo o próprio caractere de fim de linha - `\n` (como é óbvio, é o último caractere da string retornada). E é por isso que a impressão não está não está sendo feita do modo desejado.

Então, você poderia optar por substituir o último caractere da string por um espaço em branco.

Ex:

```
linha1[strlen(linha1) -1 ] = ' ';
strcpy(l1->produtos,linha1);
```

Comment: Além das mudanças que você sugeriu, é necessário colocar um `\n` ao final do print. Adicionalmente, seria legal adicionar um link para a documentação da função `fgets`, como esse http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html

Comment: @mercador, [fgets em cpprference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) tem informações mais amigáveis.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi os manuais POSIX (opengrup) costumam ser mais precisos e compatíveis com o padrão, com menos ênfase em *extensões*.

Comment: @mercador, entendo seu ponto. cppreference não documenta extensões.

Answer (score -1):

O codigo informado na pergunta não está no estilo do C++.

Reescrevi usando as bibliotecas do C++. Compilado com:

g++ -std=c++11 stackoverflow.cpp -o stackoverflow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream entrada("entrada.txt");
    string linha;

    while (getline(entrada, linha)) {
        cout << " - " << linha << ";" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```